# Qt OpenGL Render to texture Performance Issue

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, embedded

To give a background about the problem,I want to implement some image processing on the openGL rendering. So i decided to use the concept of Render to Texture. This implementation is in Qt/OpenGL and targt Embedded platform. The window size is 1280*720.

The problem is without the Render to texture i am able to achieve around 47fps and with Render to texture the fps drops to 20.

What i am doing right now is that I create a frame buffer in Qt by using QOpenGLFramebufferObject and this is how i initialize it in InitializeGL(). Size 1280*720.

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
m_fbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, format);
```

In PaintGL() function I bind the frame buffer first do all the rendering and generate the texture from this frame buffer to which i apply the image processing. In the code below the OnTrip() function is the OpenGL rendering. Inside drawOpticalDistortedTexture() I am binding the buffer and drawing the texture using glDrawElements() function in Qt.

```
void MainWidget::paintGL()
{

   if (!tripEnded)
   {
       m_fbo->bind();
       onTrip();
   }
   else
   {
       m_fbo->bind();
       onEndTrip(); 
   }
   QImage imagefbo = m_fbo->toImage();
   m_fbo->release();

   QOpenGLTexture* textureProcessed = initTexturesHelper(imagefbo);
   glViewport(SCR_WIDTH_OFFSET, SCR_HEIGHT_OFFSET, (GLsizei)SCR_WIDTH, (GLsizei)SCR_HEIGHT);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   /*************************** Post processed Drawing *********************************************/
   programOpticalDistortion.bind();
   modelMatrix.setToIdentity();
   programOpticalDistortion.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", getOrthoProjectionMatrix() * modelMatrix);
   programOpticalDistortion.setUniformValue("tex", 0);
   programOpticalDistortion.setUniformValue("k1", distortionFactor);
   programOpticalDistortion.setUniformValue("screenDimen", screenDimension);
   textureProcessed->bind();
   // Draw Texture geometry
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   geometries->drawOpticalDistortedTexture(&programOpticalDistortion);
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
   textureProcessed->release();
   programOpticalDistortion.release();
   /*************************** Post processed Drawing - End *********************************************/

   ++frameCount;
   if (frameTime.elapsed() >= 1000)
   {
       float fps = frameCount / ((double)frameTime.elapsed() / 1000.0f);
       qDebug() << "FPS" << "  " << fps ;
   }
}
```

The VS shader is as below,

```
#version 300 es
uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;
in vec4 a_position;
in vec2 a_texcoord;
out vec2 v_texcoord;
void main()
{
   // Calculate vertex position in screen space
   gl_Position = mvp_matrix * a_position;
   v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
```

The fragment shader is as below,

```
#version 300 es
#undef lowp
#undef mediump
#undef highp

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform float k1;
uniform vec2 screenDimen;

in vec2 v_texcoord;
out vec4 out_color;

 //! [0]
void main()
{
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy / screenDimen.xy) - vec2(0.5);
    float uva = atan(uv.x, uv.y);
    float uvd = sqrt(dot(uv, uv));
    uvd = uvd*(1.0 + k1*uvd*uvd);
    out_color = texture(tex, vec2(0.5) + vec2(sin(uva), cos(uva))*uvd);
}
```

I don't have any issues with final output but the fps is the major concern now, How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Are you testing an unoptimized debug build or an optimized release build?

Comment: Hi jesper, when i posted the question i was on debug mode, as per your suggestion i checked release version, the fps is around 25 now but not sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were 2 issues

1. The dynamic texture textureProcessed I created in `PaintGL()` was not deleted at the end of the cycle. Added delete textureProcessed; which improved the performance but didnt achieve 60 FPS.
2. In the `main()` function I had these lines which sets the Surface format for rendering.

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLES);
format.setVersion(2, 0);
```

When these lines were commented the FPS raised to 60. Somehow its the issue with Qt's internal Surface format settings. Its not mandatory to set the surface format, the OpenGL will still work.

Comment: @mechnicov Thanks for the edit. I am not sure why have you closed this question.

Comment: I didn't close, even didn't vote for that

Comment: The message says the question needs debugging details and hence the question will be closed.

Comment: Yes, someone voted to close it. Not me